# How to get `devtools::install_deps` to repsect `(<= version)` restrictions?

Tags: r, devtools

For a package I am developing, I have the following Imports: in `DESCRIPTION` file

```r
Imports:
  forecast (<= 0.8.7)
```

However, when I try to install the package using `devtools::install_deps` it installs the latest version of `forecast` instead of respecting the version restriction.

How do install packages locally that also respects the restrictions in `DESCRIPTION`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, perhaps file a new [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues)?